# Appendix label showing the last chapter's

Tags: appendix

I'm writing a thesis and so I have multiple files (6 chapters in all). At the end of my main, I have 4 entries for appendices. Each has more then one page. On the top of the second page of each, instead of being 'Appendix A. title' or 'Appendix B:.title' and so on, it shows (for all): 'Chapter 6. Conclusions and future work'. Any idea how I can change that?

```
....

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics
\appendix

\chapter{title}
\includepdf[offset=70 -70, scale=0.8, pages=- , pagecommand={}]{name.pdf}

\chapter{title}
\includepdf[offset=70 -70, scale=0.8, pages=- , pagecommand={}]{name.pdf}

\chapter{title}
\includepdf[offset=70 -70, scale=0.8, pages=- , pagecommand={}]{name.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted is directly related to your problem? Based on what you posted, there seems to be no reason for the behavior you describe. Also, it would help if you post more info (an MWE maybe?). Because as it is now it is virtually impossible for us where the `Conclusions and future work` count come from

Comment: If your appendices are also created with TeX, it might make sense to `\include` the `.tex`-file instead of using `\includepdf`